# Horizontal Dat.GUI

Tags: css, dat.gui

How can I make the [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) items spaced horizontally? Say we only have 2 or 3 parameters and they can  all  fit in one line, like a navbar at the top or bottom of the page.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change dat.gui styles. There is no configuration option for orientation...